# Three data sets in the KQL chart

Tags: azure, data-visualization, kql

I have three data sets:

| RequestType | SuccessType | ClientName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| External | Full | Client 1 |
| External | Partial | Client 1 |
| External | Fail | Client 1 |
| Internal | Full | Client 1 |
| Internal | Partial | Client 1 |
| Internal | Fail | Client 1 |
| External | Full | Client 2 |
| External | Partial | Client 2 |
| External | Fail | Client 2 |
| Internal | Full | Client 2 |
| Internal | Partial | Client 2 |
| Internal | Fail | Client 2 |

And I want to visualize it like this:
[image]

Each client has two columns: External or Internal (request type) and each of this column has three sections: Full, Partial and Fail (success type).

However, I can't add series for each unstacked column. Any way how I can do that?

Here's my kql:

```
// some conditions
| summarize apiCalls = count() by client, requestType, successType
| render columnchart with (kind=unstacked)
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of visualization is not supported right now.
Please suggest and upvote at: https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice